# different behavior for commands within script vs command line, in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I include the following commands in a script, in a `Linux 66da84f81903 5.15.49-linuxkit-pr #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 25 07:27:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` system.

```
apt-get update -y && wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /home/miniconda.sh && bash /home/miniconda.sh -b && /root/mini
conda3/bin/conda init && source ~/.bashrc && conda install -c bioconda igblast -y && igblastn
```

If I run these commands manually, I get the expected results:

```
BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide database [human_gl_V] in search path [/::]
```

since I have not provided the required arguments and environmental variables to igblastn.

HOWEVER, if I run a script containing these SAME commands.
`source MyScript.sh` I get:

```
/root/miniconda3/share/igblast/bin/igblastn: error while loading shared libraries: libncbi-vdb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why?
Even though in this case I should use `source`, I also tried running it with `bash` but it doesn't work because: `==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==`

How can I run these commands WITHIN a script?

Thank you!

Comment: If you do `echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`  at the prompt, what does it say?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Thank you. It's empty. `echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" | awk '{print length($0)}'` -> `0`

Comment: Since using `source` to read and execute the lines in a file is the same typing the lines directly at a shell prompt you can't possibly be running the same commands that are in the file `MyScript.sh`. Also, why are you executing `source ~/.bashrc`? If you're doing this from an interactive shell that file has already been sourced.

Comment: @KurtisRader. Thank you. I execute ./bashrc because `miniconda.sh` previous execution modified that PATH in ./bashrc. I could modify the path myself but I am writing something that could change with time and the added path might differ.  I don't fully understand your first statement. you `can't possibly be running the same commands`? Are not the same if I am using `source`?

Comment: You said you "run these commands manually" which I take to mean you typed (or copy/pasted) that command at an interactive shell prompt. If you put that same line in a file and `source` it you will get identical behavior. Since you are getting different behavior it seems safe to conclude what is in the file is not the same as what you typed manually at a shell prompt. Also, using `&&` in that fashion in a script is bad practice, in my opinion. It's better to put `set -o errexit` at the top of the script then run each command separately without the `&&` to link them.